# Does regular polymorphic association work in this case?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, polymorphic-associations

I have four models and these associations

```
forums
  belongs to user
  has many topics
topics
  belongs to user AND forum (at the same time)
  has many posts
posts
  belongs to topic AND user (at the same time)
users
  has many forums
  has many topics
  has many posts
```

The problem I am trying to figure out is how to deal with

```
topics  
  belongs to user AND forum (at the same time)
posts
  belongs to topic AND user (at the same time)
```

[It seems like regular polymorphic association only supports cases where you have EITHER OR scenario rather than AND scenario.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations)

So for example, I think regular polymorphic association only supports a case like

```
comments
  belongs to EITHER photo OR blog
```

Instead of

```
comments
  belongs to posts AND commenter
```

Would regular polymorphic association work? If not, what other options do I have?

Comment: If they belong to both at the same time there is no reason for you to use polymorphic associations?

Comment: I see. I guess I had a wrong idea of what polymorphic association is. What should do in my current case?

Comment: dont you think it will just complicate things, why dont you simply say  topic belongs to forum, and topics belongs to owner, user has many topics etc

Comment: @garbagecollection you should just create the foreign keys to those tables and be done with it.

Comment: Thank you Amol and Mauricio. I am going to try the regular way using foreign keys.